# Jquery don't work css function

Tags: jquery, mousehover

At the time of loading the page with ajax and display the html with javascript there is I insert the css but it does not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".potot").hover(
            function (e) {
            $(".titles").css("display","block");
            $.ajax({url:"title/title.php?n="+this.id,success:function(result){
            id("titles2").innerHTML = result;   
            }});
        }, 
        function (e) {
       $(".titles").css("display","none");
        });
     });
```

Dont work ...

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` are your friends :)

Comment: wat id("titles2").innerHTML = result;  this represent..

Answer (score 3):

What is `id("titles2")` referencing? do you mean to use `$('#titles2').href(result);`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".potot").hover(
            function (e) {
           // $(".titles").css("display","block");
              $(".titles").show();
              $.ajax({url:"title/title.php?n="+this.id,success:function(result){
            //id("titles2").innerHTML = result;  
              $("#titles2").html(result); 
            }});
        }, 
        function (e) {
       //$(".titles").css("display","none");
          $(".titles").hide();
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much Jon Erickson and Vivek, I've got the solution above problems.

"Wrong Function "

```
$(".potot").hover(
```

"Change With "

```
$(".potot").live("hover",function(e){
```

Maybe someday I will need help from you, thank you for the answer.